# Why mutable object(NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary) required alloc- init?while we can directly assign value to immutable objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, mutable

```
//Mutable object...


//first initialize

NSMutablearray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


//then add value

[arr addobjects:@"iPhone",@"Android",nil];




//But we can assign value immutable array without initialize

NSArray *brr=@[@"iPhone",@"Android"];
```

Comment: Can you please shorten your title and add the relevant information and the problem you are having in the question body?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to initialize `NSMutableArray`. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"iPhone", @"Android", nil];
```

The `@[]` literal syntax is a fairly new addition to ObjC, and it returns an `NSArray` (non-mutable), which is why you can't assign it directly to an `NSMutableArray`. It's just syntactic sugar for `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`. If you want to use that syntax, you still can, though:

```
NSArray *brr = [@[@"iPhone",@"Android"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: It is important to note that there is **no direct assignment** of immutable values beyond syntactic sugar.  The syntax is simply shorthand for a dynamic method invocation;  there is no difference between the short hand and the method invocation form, as far as what the compiler outputs.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way the literal syntax is. In Objective-C, it creates an `NSArray`. If you really want to use the syntax but end up with a mutable array you can use a copy like this:

```
NSMutableArray *brr=@[@"iPhone",@"Android"].mutableCopy;
```

This system is much better in Swift, where it's just one value type called `Array` and you set mutability with either a `var` or a `let`

```
var myArray = ["iPhone", "Android"] // mutable
let myArray = ["iPhone", "Android"] // immutable
```

Answer (score 1):

You object to the two-step process:

```
//first initialize
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//then add value
[arr addobjects:@"iPhone",@"Android",nil];
```

And you say you would rather write a *literal* array:

```
NSArray *brr=@[@"iPhone",@"Android"];
```

So combine them:

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: @[@"iPhone",@"Android"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the literal's type is immutable. Also, you should remember NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray. You can assign an instance of subclass to its superclass, but not otherwise.